# Can we autorefresh angular js code in browser when it is changed?

Tags: angularjs, webpack, server, watch

I want refresh my angular js code in browser whenever we change the code.
something like codewatcher in angular js.

**Same as**

- Angular-2
- Nodemon in NodeJS

i tried to integrate live-server using npm in angular js code but it is not worked for me.

is there any way to integrate auto detect of code changes in angular js?

Comment: For angular1 use angularjs tag.